# Get Date Filter on PivotTable row

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table

I'm creating PivotTables in Excel 2016.  The first Row field is a Date.  A few months ago I managed to apply a `Date Filter` to this row field, as shown below.  But I am now unable to reproduce this: No matter how I access filters for that row field in a new PivotTable I can only choose between `Label` and `Value` filters.

I have confirmed that the Number Format of the `DateEntry` row field is of type `Date`.  How do I get the PivotTable to offer a `Date Filter` like this?

[image: PivotTable with Date Filter on row]

Comment: Please check if the date value in source table is format as Text but not Date. Change format to Date in source table and then refresh PivotTable.

Comment: @Lee: That was it!  I added some data to the source table that (I failed to notice) lost that format.  Once I formatted all as Date, the Date Filter reappeared!